# Replace com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory Wildfly23 JDK17

Tags: java, java-17, jboss-eap-7, srv, wildfly-23

Our application server is Jboss 7.4 (Wildfly 23) and when I switched from JDK11 to JDK17 I got the runtime exception:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext cannot access class com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory (in module jdk.naming.dns) because module jdk.naming.dns does not export com.sun.jndi.dns to unnamed module @500cd973

Why we use DnsContextFactory is because we want to do a search (from Java) for ldap domains in the SRV records, code in app:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory"); // replace?
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns:");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env); // throws exception
Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes("_ldap._tcp.mydomain.com", new String[]{"SRV"}); 
Attribute a = attributes.get("SRV");
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I can resolve this by adding VM argument during start-up:
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS --add-exports=jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=ALL-UNNAMED"
but I rather not, my understanding is that add-export will fail in the fututer (JDK21?) and I am lokking for a better long term solution.

Edit:
If I start my Jboss 7.4 with JDK11 it all works fine, but if I start it with JDK17 the module is now “hidden” and unavailable. Is there another way to search the SRV-records than using DnsContextFactory from com.sun?

Comment: You might want to add the [tag:java] tag so that your question is seen by more. The [tag:java-17] tag is watched by very few people.

Comment: Java 17 is supported in JBoss EAP 7.4, but as far as I know not in JBoss EAP 7.3. I'd suggest contacting support to learn about the migration path. Also, this looks like an issue with the deployment, not necessarily JBoss EAP. You likely need to add the module to your JAVA_OPTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by replacing the code that creates the DirContext to:

```
    import javax.naming.spi.NamingManager;

    DirContext context = (DirContext) NamingManager.getURLContext("dns", new Hashtable<String, Object>());
```